# Can't connect to Azure SQL DB - pyodbc Operational Error

Tags: python, sql-server, azure-sql-database, pyodbc, azure-sql-server

Attempting to connect to an Azure SQL database, most other configurations I've tried result in an instant error:

> Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

But this one I'm currently trying times out and is the closest I've got:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', server='tcp:mydatabase.database.windows.net:1433', database='MyDatabase', user='username', password='password')
```

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Did you try configure and test connection with windows odbc data sources ? Maybe you didn’t exposed correctly your db on network

Comment: the same configuration works perfectly in datagrip and sqlpro

Comment: On same computer ? With same network configurations ? Like vpn etc

Comment: try with raw connection string like pyodbc.connect('SERVER=host;PORT=port;DATABASE=default database name;DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};UID=user;PWD=password'); host without the 'tcp:'

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for the connection string to include the default SQL Server port, which is 1433.

Add server name without **`tcp`**, use `tcp:` before quotes of servername, ***Server name format*** is `servername.database.windows.net`

***Example String***

```py
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The port defined on the server attribute is separated by comma and not colon.

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 1x for SQL Server};Server=[tcp]:{serverName}.database.windows.net[,1433]; (...)
```

You can check a sample of the connection string on the connections string blade on your database page on Azure Portal.